# How to fill Cordova Email Composer fields with variables

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to use Cordova plugin called Email Composer to let users send emails. [Cordova Email Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer)

I am generating some html content and want to prefill body of the email with the content.

The code I have tried:

```
 function emailHtml(text) //variable to fill the body
 {
      cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(
          function (isAvailable) {
               cordova.plugins.email.open({
                   to:      'your@email',
                   cc:      'second@mail',
                   bcc:     [],
                   subject: 'Greetings',
                   body:    text   //the HTML content
               });
          }
      );
 }
```

But it does not work yet.

What is the proper way to use variables for the plugins fields?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do it by plain Javascript , No need to add additional plugin and increase the build size

```
let Link="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Hello%20again";
    window.open(Link, "_system");
```

You can add all the parameter you need in the link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parameter `isHtml:    true`

```
myHTML="<html> ......... </html>";

cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(
      function (isAvailable) {
           cordova.plugins.email.open({
               to:      'your@email',
               cc:      'second@mail',
               bcc:     [],
               subject: 'Greetings',
               body:    myHTML,   //the HTML content
               isHtml:    true // indicats if the body is HTML or plain text
           });
      }
  );
```

Comment: Sorry. I have it actually true. But still does not work.

Comment: It seems like I passed my variable wrong way. Thanks anyway.